# Error using grunt-crx task

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gruntjs

I'm using the grunt-crx task in my Gruntfile like so:

```
crx: {
            packExtension: {
                src: "../build/unpacked",
                dest: "../build/dist"
            }
        }
```

When running the crx task (by itself) I get the following error message:

```
Warning: Object function lodash(value) {
    // exit early if already wrapped
    if (value && value.__wrapped__) {
      return value;
    }
    // allow invoking `lodash` without the `new` operator
    if (!(this instanceof lodash)) {
      return new lodash(value);
    }
    this.__wrapped__ = value;
  } has no method 'assign' Use --force to continue
```

And using '--force' with grunt from the command line to run the task also results in the same error.

I'm new to grunt and grunt-crx, so I'm not sure if this is a grunt issue or it's specific to the grunt-crx task, but any help getting this working would be much appreciated!

As a note, I've tried the following things without any luck.

1. Not using relative paths
2. Specifying a pem file in addition to src and dest
3. Moving ../build/unpacked to ./packed so everything was in the same directory (I've had to either do this or use the force option with other grunt tasks.)
   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, looks like the author introduced a bug in version 0.2.1 that didn't exist in 0.2.0. Uninstall your current version:

npm uninstall grunt-crx --save-dev

Then install the previous version:

npm install grunt-crx@0.2.0 --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed tied to the version of lodash I tested the extension (which was older than the one introducing `assign`).

The `0.2.2` release addresses this issue.

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Great tool btw!